# Run-time check failure #02

Tags: c

I'm working with C & I receive this error when I run my program. The error occurs when I enter the character "e" to close the program. Please help me!!! Thanks. :)

```
int main () {
while (true){
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
char wanted;
int c;
printf("Enter What You Want...\n");
printf("f for flower\n");
printf("m for mushroom\n");
printf("b for box\n");
printf("h for mario\n");
printf("e to close\n");
scanf("%s", &wanted);
if (wanted=='f'){
/*some codes here*/
}
else if (wanted=='m'){
/*some codes here*/
     }
    else if (wanted=='b'){
/*some code here*/
    }
    else if (wanted=='h'){
/*some codes here*/
    }
    else if (wanted=='e'){
         printf("Bye.\n");
         break;
    }
        else {
            printf("It Was'n a Possible Input. Try Again...\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s", &wanted);` should instead be `scanf("%c", &wanted);`

A format string of `%s` indicates that the argument to `scanf` will be a char array.  You have a single char so need to use `%c`